# Convexity of sum and intersection of convex sets

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis

> Let $A_i$ be a subset of $\Bbb{R}^m$ which is convex for $i=1,...,n$. How can I prove that the sum of $A_i$ is also convex?

I know how to prove it with two sets:

Let $x = a_1 + b_1$ and $y = a_2 + b_2$ be two points of $A + B$, where $a_i \in A$, $b_i \in B$, $i= 1,2$.
For $t \in [0,1]$, $$tx + (1-t)y = ta_1 + tb_1 + (1-t)a_2 + (1-t)b_2 = ( ta_1 + (1-t)a_2 ) + (tb_1 + (1-t)b_2)$$
which is a sum of a point in $A$ (as $A$ is convex, the convex combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$, both in $A$, is still in $A$)
and a point of $B$ (same reasoning), so is in $A + B$.
So $A + B$ is convex.

> Also, how can I prove that the $A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_n$ is convex if $A_i$ is convex?

Comment: Holy crap, that was a mess. Thanks @TBongers for the edit.

Comment: @AlexR No problem. For the benefit of the asker, your questions will likely get a better response if typed in [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have you tried inducting on n?

Comment: I know that I have to use proof by induction, but I don't know how I can show it though.

Comment: You don't need induction. Just do exactly the same proof as for $n=2$, perhaps changing notation: $x=a_1+\cdots +a_n$, $y=b_1+\cdots +b_n$, ... By the way, $A_1\times \cdots\times A_n$ should be $A_1+\cdots +A_n$.

Comment: By that I meant the intersection of Ai sets being convex since A1,...,An are individually convex. So are x and y vectors in n-dimension?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well your post (I forgot to see the "also").

Comment: Is this correct?

Let x be a vector with components (a1,...,an) and y be a vector with components (b1,...,bn).

Then for t on the interval [0,1] we get: tx + (1-t)y = (ta1 + (1-t)a2) + (tb1 + (1-t)b2) + ... + (tan + (1-t)an) + ...+ (tbn + (1-t)bn) which is a sum of points in A and sum of points of B. So the points are in A + B. Hence A + B is convex since A is convex and B is convex.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. In the general case you have $n$ sets $A_i$, not just 2. So what I had in mind is just to write the vector $x\in A_1+\cdots +A_n$ as $x=a_1+\dots +a_n$, and likewise $y=b_1+\cdots +b_n$. The $a_i$, $b_i$'s should not be the components of your vectors. Nevertheless, your proof is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof that $A+B$ is convex for convex $A$ and $B$ is correct, the general case follows by induction.

If $A_i\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ for $i=1,...,n$ then $A_1\times...\times A_n$ is convex in $\Bbb R^{mn}$:
Let $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,...b_n)$ where $a_i,b_i\in A_i$ for each $i$. Then $tb+(1-t)a=(tb_1+(1-t)a_1,...,tb_n+(1-t)a_n)$ is an element of the product since all $A_i$ are convex.